# How do I make a new line in swift

Tags: string, swift

Is there a way to have a way to make a new line in swift like "\n" for java?

```
var example: String = "Hello World \n This is a new line"
```

Comment: This is correct and valid for swift as well (depends on where you'll use this string of course, in a label title, you might not get multiple lines without setting label property as well). Remove the space before the next line then you'll get what you need.

Comment: How are you printing the line?  In a UI of some kind?  On a CLI?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You should be able to use `\n` inside a Swift string, and it should work as expected, creating a newline character. You will want to remove the space after the `\n` for proper formatting like so:

```
var example: String = "Hello World \nThis is a new line"
```

Which, if printed to the console, should become:

```
Hello World
This is a new line
```

However, there are some other considerations to make depending on how you will be using this string, such as:

- If you are setting it to a UILabel's text property, make sure that the UILabel's numberOfLines = 0, which allows for infinite lines.
- In some networking use cases, use `\r\n` instead, which is the Windows newline.

**Edit**: You said you're using a UITextField, but it does not support multiple lines. You must use a UITextView.

Answer (score 47):

Also useful:

```
let multiLineString = """
                  Line One
                  Line Two
                  Line Three
                  """
```

- Makes the code read more understandable
- Allows copy pasting

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following code;

```
var example: String = "Hello World \r\n This is a new line"
```

Comment: \r\n is better than \n for ZawGyi font in our country

Answer (score 5):

You can do this

```
textView.text = "Name: \(string1) \n" + "Phone Number: \(string2)"
```

The output will be

Name: output of string1
Phone Number: output of string2

Answer (score 4):

### `"\n"` is not working everywhere!

For example in email, it adds the exact "\n" into the text instead of a new line if you use it in the custom keyboard like: `textDocumentProxy.insertText("\n")`

There are another newLine characters available but I can't just simply paste them here (**Because they make a new lines**).

using this extension:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    var allCharacters: [Character] {
        var result: [Character] = []
        for plane: UInt8 in 0...16 where self.hasMember(inPlane: plane) {
            for unicode in UInt32(plane) << 16 ..< UInt32(plane + 1) << 16 {
                if let uniChar = UnicodeScalar(unicode), self.contains(uniChar) {
                    result.append(Character(uniChar))
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

you can access all characters in any `CharacterSet`. There is a character set called `newlines`. Use one of them to fulfill your requirements:

```
let newlines = CharacterSet.newlines.allCharacters
for newLine in newlines {
    print("Hello World \(newLine) This is a new line")
}
```

Then store the one you tested and worked everywhere and use it anywhere.
Note that you can't relay on the index of the character set. It may change.

**But most of the times** `"\n"` just works as expected.

Comment: `CharacterSet.newlines` includes 5 characters `(U+000A ~ U+000D, U+0085, U+2028, and U+2029)` and appending all of them makes no sense. Also scanning so many characters when it's known which are the 2 you are looking for (`\r` and `\n`) is not efficient.

Comment: ‘allCharacters’ means you should append all characters. I don’t know the nonsense. Can you explain please? Also as I mentioned, those two are not working everywhere. And also you should bench mark to see if it is efficient enough or not in your use case ;)

Comment: The question was "How do I make a new line in swift". Characters `U+2028`, and `U+2029` are not making a "new line", although they do control lines and paragraphs. So both characters are irrelevant to the question. Secondly, "store the one you tested and worked everywhere" - there's no such thing. There are specific rules about which characters work where. Finally, why discover them, if they are well defined in Unicode standards (see https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.2.0/ch05.pdf#G10213)?